# How to cap ko.observable and drop remainder into another field

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

I have a `ko.observable`, called **Amount**, that stores a numeric value.  I need a method for capping the numeric amount at a specific upper bound (upper bound number is provided by a `ko.computed`, called **Max**, within the same ViewModel.)  When the user tries to enter a value for **Amount** that exceeds **Max**, I want to take the overage and apply it to another `ko.observable`, called **Overage**, and also not allow the value of **Amount** to exceed the value of **Max**.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You can most likely extend your observable, depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve.  This should give you a good direction (I haven't dropped it into a fiddle to test it yet) -</strike>

```
ko.extenders.overage = function(target, max) {
    target.overage = ko.observable();
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target(),
                valueToWrite = newValue > max ? max : newValue

            if (valueToWrite === max) {
                target.overage(current - max);
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
            }
        }
    });

    result(target());

    return result;
};

function AppViewModel(one) {
    this.myNumberOne = ko.observable(one).extend({ overage: 500 });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(221.2234));
```

Now your observable `myNumberOne` has an extended property called `overage` for any additional amount over the `max` that is set when you extend it (in this case, 500) and the vlaue of myNumberOne or any other observable that you extend will cap out at 500 and pass the additional as overage.

In your view you could use this something like this -

```
<span data-bind="text: myNumberOne"></span>
<!-- ko if: myNumberOne().overage -->
    Overage amount - <span data-bind="text: myNumberOne().overage"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

or

```
<span data-bind="text: myNumberOne"></span>
<div data-bind="text: $data.myNumberOne().overage"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DNxHu/

Extend it and subscribe to it, don't use a computed, etc...  Check the fiddle

Comment: Trying to get this working in JSFiddle... there is an init for a ko.computed?

Comment: Good question.  Let me double check that : )  If not just hit it on the initializer and subscribe to before changes, let me edit the answer

Comment: Updated, sorry about that, I will try to throw it into a fiddle to make sure it acts as expected

Comment: Closer, the capping is taking place (after a couple minor syntax fixes) but the overage is still not coming through, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yep, looking at it in fiddle now, the problem is inside of that extender overage is being registered on target but that isn't moving over to the computed, which makes sense.  I need to work on a few other things but I will swing back around and clean that up, should give you a general direction to go though even if it isn't functioning 100%

Comment: Thanks very much.  Still can't quite get the overage working.

Comment: since you're adding the member overage to the target you should be returning target from the extender.

Comment: It's not the prettiest fiddle but through another option together.  Updating answer